# create a custom currency filter using angular in the simplest way possible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, format, currency

I am creating a custom currency filter in angular js. Everything is working, but I want to see if there's an easier way to simply some of my code.

Here is where I pass the filter.

```
   <p>{{ 44.95 | formatCurrency }}</p>
```

Ideally I will get the market from the api, but for now I'm just mocking it:

```
.filter('formatCurrency', function(currencyService){
    //from api call
    let market = 'Br';

    return function(number) {
      const marketFormat = currencyService.get(market);
      let output;

      number = number.toString().replace('.', marketFormat.decimalDelimiter);
      addCurrencySymbol(number);

      function addCurrencySymbol(number){
        const symbol = marketFormat.currencySign;
        number = marketFormat.showsBefore ? symbol + number : number + symbol;
        addSpecialString(number);
      }

      function addSpecialString(number){
        const specialString = marketFormat.specialString;
        if (specialString) {
          number = marketFormat.showsStringBefore ? specialString + ' ' + number : number  + ' ' + specialString;
        }
        output = number
      }

      return output;
    }
});
```

I'm using a service called currencyService to get the data properties of the way the market likes the currency filtered:

```
.service('currencyService', function(){

  function get(market){
    let numberFormatForMarket = {
      US: { decimalDelimiter: '.', currencySign: '$', showsBefore: true, specialString: null },
      UK: { decimalDelimiter: '.', currencySign: '£', showsBefore: true, specialString: null },
      FR: { decimalDelimiter: ',', currencySign: '€', showsBefore: false, specialString: null },
      ES: { decimalDelimiter: ',', currencySign: '€', showsBefore: false, specialString: null },
      BEnl: { decimalDelimiter: ',', currencySign: '€', showsBefore: false, specialString: null },
      BEfr: { decimalDelimiter: ',', currencySign: '€', showsBefore: false, specialString: null },
      CAen: { decimalDelimiter: '.', currencySign: '$', showsBefore: false, specialString: 'C', showsStringBefore: true },
      CAfr: { decimalDelimiter: ',', currencySign: '$', showsBefore: false, specialString: 'C', showsStringBefore: false },
      SE: { decimalDelimiter: '.', currencySign: '', showsBefore: false, specialString: 'kr', showsStringBefore: false },
      AU: { decimalDelimiter: '.', currencySign: '$', showsBefore: true, specialString: 'A', showsStringBefore: true },
      NZ: { decimalDelimiter: '.', currencySign: '$', showsBefore: true, specialString: 'NZ', showsStringBefore: true },
      DE: { decimalDelimiter: ',', currencySign: '€', showsBefore: false, specialString: null },
      NL: { decimalDelimiter: ',', currencySign: '€', showsBefore: false, specialString: null },
      CHfr: { decimalDelimiter: '.', currencySign: '', showsBefore: true, specialString: 'Fr.', showsStringBefore: true },
      CHde: { decimalDelimiter: '.', currencySign: '', showsBefore: true, specialString: 'Fr.', showsStringBefore: true },
      Br: { decimalDelimiter: ',', currencySign: '$', showsBefore: true, specialString: 'R', showsStringBefore: true },

    }

    return numberFormatForMarket[market];
  }

  return {
    get
  }
```

Here is the code: https://embed.plnkr.co/GJELOhMSECxXpCm9J3V9/
My main question: I'm working hard on trying to write CLEAN CODE. Is there anything major I can do here to simplify things?

Comment: I mean, that looks pretty simple to me. You could make it even SIMPLER though by not using a filter at all and instead moving most/all of that functionality into a function that gets called like `<p>{{myCurrencyFunc(44.45)}}</p>` But just saying, that might not be best practice.

Comment: Yea that would be against best practice, thanks though.